# ANDROID STUDIO: Restricción de valor nulo en la primer posición EditText

Tags: android

necesito su ayuda! me gustaría saber como puedo hacer una "restricción" donde NO PERMITA que el primer valor en la primer posición que inserte en mi editText sea el número CERO. Por ejemplo: 0123 (NO DEBERÍA DEJARME HACER ESO). Les agradecería mucho si me compartieran su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Debes declarar en la interfaz que ese edittext es número

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Tab 1"/>
```

Ahora, en la clase declaramos el EditText:

```
EditText et1;
```

Le diremos a ese EditText en el onResume() que si está vacío no guarde el dato:

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(et1.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El campo no puede estar vacío",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Guardado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

Y ahora, respondiendo a tu pregunta, para que no nos permita guardar ni iniciar el dato con el valor 0 (cero) utilizaremos el addTextChangedListener (todo esto sigue estando dentro del onResume()):

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(et1.getText().toString().equals(0+"")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El primer caracter no puede iniciar en 0 (cero)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//Acá le decimos que si el dato empieza con 0 nos muestre un mensaje
                    et1.setText("");//Acá le decimos que si el usuario ingresa un 0 lo borre automáticamente
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
```

Esa es la respuesta a tu pregunta, espero que te haya servido. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha servido de mucha ayuda! Solo me queda la duda ... ¿Qué significa exactamente onResume()?. ¿Es parte del ciclo de vida de la activity?

Comment: He llegado tarde con la respuesta pero sí, el onResume es parte del ciclo de vida. A diferencia del onCreate, el onResume es usado para las actividades que van de la mano con el usuario